# Clearing positioned items

Tags: html, css, mediawiki

At [link dead; should have taken a pic of the site] I want the black box and the category box to appear below the red one. I use css positioning the remove the unwanted excess space between the page title and the main text. Is there a way to fix this problem with just inline css and html per wiki restrictions?

Comment: I don't see a black box.

Comment: The link is broken; it includes the ( but not the ). There is a black box if you put in the ).

Comment: And having looked at it, I would say no, there isn't really a way to do that with CSS; if you want something to naturally appear below something else, they need to be next to each other in the HTML. Absolute positioning will not do this nicely, since each positioned element can't take into account the size of the others, and none of them will take up any space in the layout.

Comment: Wait, I still don't see a black box... I'm on Chrome 9, on XP x64 Pro. I see an orange infobox, and the category box at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You mean using something like https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Template:Clear ?